# Creating an array of PCA objects in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn, pca

I have a problem where I'd like to apply PCA with varying number of components to the same dataset.

I assumed that It was possible to create an array of PCA objects with different component sizes and then use them later on the data.

But, I'm getting an error while I'm trying to run the following code.

```html
pca_sizes = np.array([10,50,100,250,500])
samples = np.shape(pca_sizes)
for i in range(len(pca_sizes)):
    pca_comp[i] = PCA(n_components = pca_sizes[i])
```

and I get the following error

```html
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [50], in <cell line: 3>()
      2 samples = np.shape(pca_sizes)
      3 for i in range(len(pca_sizes)):
----> 4     pca_comp[i] = PCA(n_components = pca_sizes[i])

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'PCA'
```

I tried looking up, but it seems like I don't quite understand how arrays work since I'm coming from a C background.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] to include the full traceback of the error rather than just the last line, as that contains valuable information

Comment: Yes I did add the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind figured it out. Apparently, I can use this ternary operator to generate lists of different types, objects, sizes etc etc.

```html
pca_sizes = np.array([10,50,100,250,500])
pca_comp = [PCA(n_components = i) for i in (pca_sizes)]
```

This apparently can be used to store multi dimensional arrays with varying sizes too.

Anyways, I donot understand this nearly well enough to make proper explanation of how this works.

But this will fix the issue I see here.